# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'vX' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys once again I ran into a flaw in my game code for school... So here I am trying to add in my "Player Rocket" so this is the code the book just had me add under all my generated Asteroids.

```
    player.vX = 0;
    player.vY = 0;

    if (player.moveRight) {
        player.vX = 3;
    };

    if (player.moveUp) {
        player.vY = -3;
    };

    if (player.moveDown) {
        player.vY = 3;
    };

    player.x += player.vX;
    player.y += player.vY;

    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(player.x+player.halfWidth, player.y);
    context.lineTo(player.x-player.halfWidth, player.y-player.halfHeight);
    context.lineTo(player.x-player.halfWidth, player.y+player.healfHeight);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
```

Now the error I keep getting it this...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'vX' of undefined

I've looked through the book to see if I had to define this some where but I didn't miss anything. Now I am still realy new to this but the only spot i see me using `player.vX` is here.

```
var player;
var Player = function(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = 24;
    this.height = 24;
    this.halfWidth = this.width/2;
    this.halfHeight = this.height/2;
    this.moveRight = false;
    this.moveUp = false;
    this.moveDown = false;

    this.vX = 0;
    this.vY = 0;
};
```

If anyone could help me out and better understand this that would be great! Thank You!!!

Comment: where did you create an instance of Player class??

Comment: If that code came from a book, throw the book out your window and find another one.

Comment: could you post it on fiddle so we can see the error directly with all this canvas things? thanks

Comment: @Misters what do you mean by player class?

Comment: @ChristophHa just did it never used fiddle before so let me know if this link works http://jsfiddle.net/MK6d5/

Comment: Thanks but I cant do it today, if this is mit solved I try to help tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

When you say `var player;`, you're setting `player` to undefined. You need to create a new instance of a `Player()`. You can do this by

```
var player=new Player(xCoord,yCoord);
```

That book is plain wrong, if it thinks that initiating something with a similar name as the constructor will instantiate a new Player.

To learn more about objects, you should take a look at [MDN's tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: could u take a look at it on fiddle the full code is there. I just dont know how i would set up what u just told me. http://jsfiddle.net/MK6d5/